# libxml2 xmlTextReaderRead return -1

Tags: c++, libxml2

I use libxml2 to parse big xml file.I refer to the [example](http://www.xmlsoft.org/xmlreader.html).when xml node value is large(more than 4M),xmlTextReaderRead alway return -1.I am sure xml file is right. Is it libxml2's bug?What should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to parse multi-megabyte text nodes, you have to use the [`XML_PARSE_HUGE`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlParserOption) option. So instead of `xmlNewTextReaderFilename`, use the [`xmlReaderForFile`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlreader.html#xmlReaderForFile) constructor which allows to pass parser options:

```
reader = xmlReaderForFile(filename, NULL, XML_PARSE_HUGE);
```

This option is disabled by default to prevent DoS attacks.